# Confused. CA1063 is wrong? GC.SuppressFinalize(this)

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I have a simple class MyDataClass with a member (obj) that implements IDisposable:

```
public class MyDataClass : IDisposable
{
    private DisposableObject obj;
    private List<string> list;
    private int c;

    public MyDataClass()
    {
        obj = new DisposableObject();
        list = new List<string>();
        c = 114;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        obj.Dispose();
    }
}

public class DisposableObject : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Free resource
        Console.WriteLine("Dispose DisposableObject");
    }
}
```

When I run the Code Analysis I get the CA1063 warning which shows me that I should call **GC.SuppressFinalize()** method in the **Dispose()** method in **MyDataClass** implementation.

And I am really confused about this CA1063 warning. Because as far as I know, I should call **GC.SuppressFinalize()** to indicate to the garbage collector:

*"Hey GC, do not worry about this object because I have done already all cleaning work for you!"*

So please confirm if I am wrong or not. If I will add the **GC.SuppressFinalize()** I will get rid of the CA1063 but it will cause that GC will not clean my object. So I will have a memory leak because other class members (managed code) will be not cleaned.

Comment: If you implement IDisposable but do not implement the full IDisposable pattern, you should mark your class as sealed so that it is not possible to derive from your class and break the disposal of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I will add the `GC.SuppressFinalize()` I will get rid of the CA1063
>   but it will cause that GC will not clean my object.

No, your objects will still be collected.

> *"Hey GC, do not worry about this object because I have done already all cleaning work for you!"*

You're actually only saying: don't worry about the Finalizer (destructor) of this object. If it has one.

And that is where Code Analysis is getting it wrong: your class does have an `IDisposable.Dispose()` method but it does not have a destructor. So the warning is pointless, being over protective and triggering on the wrong reason. Disable or ignore it.

Comment: ...but during collection the finalizer (`~MyDataClass()`) will not be called (if it is defined). The full `IDisposable` pattern includes a finalizer. http://dave-black.blogspot.be/2011/03/how-do-you-properly-implement.html

Comment: @spender: It's clear that this class does not has a destructor, and that it shouldn't have one.

Comment: But consider this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538060/proper-use-of-the-idisposable-interface and the answer. It is written there that GC when it is cleaning managed resources it is calling the Finalize() method (so the destructor), so how my object will be still collected when I suppress the finalize?

Comment: @mdn Object finalization and garbage collection are two very different parts of the virtual machine.  They aren't even run on the same thread.  An object can be finalized but never garbage collected, and similarly an object might be collected but not finalized.  You almost never have to worry about the deallocation of managed memory in .NET.

Comment: Great post but the opening sentence is very wrong. Disposable is needed to clean up  unmanaged _and_ managed resources. The Finalizer is only needed for unmanaged. You will never deal with unmanaged directly, so never add a destructor.

Comment: So providing the Finalize method (I mean the destructor) is only an additional work that GC will do for us when he is collecting?  So this statement is not true, that GC is calling Finalize() on each object which is collected because without Finalize() GC will still collect the object. And GC.SuppressFinalize indicates only that GC do not need to worry about additional work given in the destructor?

Comment: Yes, if you dont add a ~dtor the GC will directly collect your object. When a dtor/Finalizer is present (and not suppressed), it becomes a lot more complicated and expensive.

Comment: I am still confused because of that what I have read in the another post (which I linked above). To be clear. GC will always clean my object AND call the Finalize() method when it is provided?

Comment: You can search for `fReachable` to read up on the GC. The short conclusion: avoid Finalizers.

Comment: @HenkHolterman The point of `Dispose` is to free unmanaged resources.  It just so happens that 99% of the time these unmanaged resources are accessed through other managed objects, hence no need for a finalizer in your own object.  If there were no unmanaged resources, `Dispose` would be a convenience, not a necessity.

Answer (score 5):

The method `GC.SuppressFinalize()` indicates to the VM not to run the *finalizer*.  That's the funny looking method in C#:

`~MyDataClass()`

To remove the warning, you need to either seal your class, or implement the complete [IDisposable pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244737.aspx).

Comment: Yes, `sealed` would be the better solution here. I wish MS would drop that full pattern (as the _only_ official one).

Comment: In favor of a pattern for managed (IDisposable) resources only, w/o a destructor.

Answer (score 5):

I have the feeling that you are still confused, despite having accepted an answer. Let me explain:

The Garbage Collector (GC) has the unenviable task to remove any objects from memory that are not reachable.

### Reachability

An object `A` is only reachable when there is any chain of references from any GC *root* to the object. Examples of roots are the stack, and any static fields. So, to determine whether `A` is reachable, all the GC has to do is to find a reference on the stack that refers to an object that has a reference that refers to an object ... that refers to object `A`. If it cannot find such a chain, object `A` is not reachable.<sup>1</sup>

So, once the GC has determined that `A` is not reachable, it will want to remove it from memory.
However, before it does that, the GC checks whether `A` has a finalizer (`~A`) that must be run. If not, it removes `A` from memory and the GC is done with it.

### Finalization

However, if `A` has a finalizer that must be run, it cannot remove the object from memory before the finalizer is finished. So, it adds a reference to `A` to the *finalizer queue* and does not remove the object from memory (yet). Now the Garbage Collector is done with `A` for now. However, when the GC runs again, it will again try to determine whether `A` is reachable. Luckily, the finalizer queue is also one of the Garbage Collector's roots, so it determines that there is a reference from the finalizer queue to `A`, therefore `A` is reachable and will again not be removed from memory.

Along comes the *finalizer thread*, a thread that periodically checks whether there are any objects in the finalizer queue. If there are, it picks one and runs its finalizer method. Eventually, the finalizer thread will run the finalizer of `A`. Once this is done, the reference to `A` is removed from the finalizer queue.

### Clean up

Then, some time later, the Garbage Collector runs again, and tries to determine again whether `A` is reachable. As it is now not referenced anywhere, not even from the finalizer queue, `A` is not reachable. The GC removes `A` from memory.

---

You see, normally the GC can remove unreachable objects in the same collection cycle it detects them, but when an object has a finalizer that needs to be run, it can take multiple cycles for the object to be collected. Therefore CA1063 recommends you to put `GC.SuppressFinalize()` in the `Dispose` method to let the GC know that the objects does not need to be finalized before it is removed from memory. So, the object is always<sup>2</sup> removed from memory eventually.

Note that when you don't have a finalizer you don't have to add `GC.SuppressFinalize()`, so in that respect the CA1063 warning is a bit superfluous.

More in-depth information about the Garbage Collector can be found [in this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx).

---

**<sup>1</sup>)** Reachability is the reason why it is common to set references to `null` after disposing them. This makes the referenced object most likely unreachable, and therefore a candidate to be removed.

**<sup>2</sup>)** It is possible (but certainly *not* recommended) to *resurrect* `A` by using the finalizer to add a reference to `A` from another reachable object or root (e.g. a static field). This makes `A` reachable again, and the Garbage Collector will not remove it. However, its finalizer will not run again, as it has already been invoked once.